# Is it ok if I create a Web Driver Instance in all my test classes or is there any way around to create it once and use everywhere in the test project

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nunit, testng

I usually create a Web Driver instance in my all test classes through out my project and then initialize it with let's say Firefox Driver. Is it the normal automation practice or shall I create it only once and use it everywhere in my project. If second one is the 'should be' case then how to achieve it.

I use web-driver with Java in one project and C# in another. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your driver in the Base calss as below:

```
public class BaseClass {

    static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Properties obj = new Properties();

        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(
                System.getProperty("user.dir")
                        + "\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
        obj.load(objfile);

        driver.get(obj.getProperty("URL"));
    }
}
```

And then you can just extend your base class as below so you you do not need to declare your driver in every class you created:

```
public class ProApp extends BaseClass{

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void clickLoginLink() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Properties obj = new Properties();

    FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"\\src\\com\\provider\\Object.Properties");
    obj.load(objfile);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(obj.getProperty("ClickOnLoginLink"))).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have created an instance of webdriver in a superclass and use it in the subclasses (test classes) whenever you need it. Since this will save time for initializing webdriver for every class.